# Berks install not including ruby snippet

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, berkshelf, berksfile

This is my berksfile:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

Dir[File.expand_path('../cookbooks', __FILE__)].each do |path|
  cookbook(File.basename(path), path: path)
end

metadata
```

I should be able to do this https://www.sethvargo.com/berksfile-magic/
But berks just ignores that code snippet and I see no output from berks that it even tries to run it, it just says "Unable to find a solution for demands:"

If I include them like this it works:

```
cookbook 'mycookbook', path: '../mycookbook'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant `Dir[File.expand_path('../cookbooks/*', __FILE__)]` but you can do this more easily if you are using ChefDK 2.x (i.e. a recent-ish Berkshelf) like so:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io/'
source chef_repo: '..'

metadata
```